# onoremap: defining a bounded region

Tags: regular-expression, range, object-motions, map-operator

I want to craft a custom operator-pending motion `if` for functions in R language that look like this:

```
doSomething <- function(arg1, arg2, ...) {
    doStuff(...)
}
```

The idea is to be able to press `yif` while on the function body to copy it's contents `doStuff(...)` in this case. I have something that works:

```
onoremap if :<c-u>execute "normal! $?<-\\s*function\\s*(\r^/{\r%``j^v``kg_"<cr>
```

This does the following: searches for the `<- function` pattern backwards, then finds the first `{`, jumps to it's match with `%`, then goes back to the beginning, goes down one line, enters visual mode, jump to the end, goes up one line and finishes.

This works for me with one downside: it finds functions even when I am outside (below) the function body.

My question is: how to make it fail when the cursor is not on a function?

Any other help/tips are appreciated as well.

#### Update

Following advice from @Luc I wrote a simple function to check if the given line is inside the function:

```
function! IsInsideRFunction(lnum)
  let currentline = a:lnum
  let savedpos = getpos(".")
  execute "silent! normal! $" . '?<-\s*function\s*(' . "\<cr>"
  execute "silent! normal! " . '/{' . "\<cr>"
  let startline = line(".")
  execute "silent! normal! %"
  let endline = line(".")
  if currentline >=# startline && currentline <=# endline
    call setpos(".", savedpos)
    return 1
  endif
  call setpos(".", savedpos)
endfunction
```

The function works. However when I put it inside the expression map:

```
onoremap <expr> aF IsInsideRFunction(line(".")) ? ":echom 'yes'<cr>" : ":echom 'no'<cr>"
```

it stops working. More precisely - it always returns "1".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Quick search, limited to a C++ function](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/quick-search-limited-to-a-c-function/7942#7942) all the techniques presented in this discussion shall apply to your question. I'm not sure my solution is checking the cursor is within a function definition.

To check for improper uses, you have to define a function. There, first record the current line, and then check the first and last line you detect do surround the initial line. If not, throw an error or do whatever you wish.

EDIT:
For instance something like:

```
" ftplugin/r.vim
onoremap <buffer> <silent> if :<c-u>call <sid>Select_current_function()<cr>
xnoremap <buffer> <silent> if :<c-u>call <sid>Select_current_function()<cr><esc>gv

function! s:Select_current_function() abort
  if 0
    " V1 that doesn't work well when the cursor is on the function declaration
    " The regex needs to be fixed
    let lin = line('.')
    let start = searchpos('<-\s*function\s*(.\{-})\s*{', 'bcenWz') " may depend on your vim version
    if start[0] == 0 
      throw "Not within a function"
    endif
    call assert_true(start[0] <= lin) " may not exist with old vim versions
    let end = searchpairpos('{', '', '}', 'nc')
    if end[0] == 0 || end[0] < lin
      throw "Not within a function"
    endif
    call cursor(start)
    normal! v
    call cursor(end)
  else

    " or, V2 that supposes that function end is always 0 indented
    " I don't know if this is valid for R
    let p = getcurpos()
    normal! ][
    if getline('.')[col('.')-1] != '}'
      call setpos('.', p)
      throw "Not within a function 1"
    endif
    normal! v%
    if line('.') > p[1] 
      call setpos('.', p)
      throw "Not within a function"
    endif
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried something similar to what you suggested and it still didn't work. Maybe you can take a quick look - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius I'd have used `search()` with the *don't move the cursor* option to search for function start and end. Otherwise, you've forgotten to return something in the second case. BTW, you don't need execute to run `silent! normal %`

Comment: I am new to this, as you can probably tell.. Thank you for all the advice. Didn't know about search - that's a good match for what I am doing, will try using it. But not having an "else" inside the function in this case does not seem to be the problem. I verified that the function works otherwise (calin IsInsideFunction() from command line). It just stops working when inside that `onoremap`

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius, the thing is that not all paths of your function return something. You can't use your function result as it may be in an unspecified state.

Comment: Hmm I really don't think that's the issue. I got this from here [Learn Vim Script The Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/23.html#implicit-returning) and it says "if a Vimscript function doesn't return a value, it implicitly returns 0". And I tried adding else - didn't help. Another thing - after restarting vim now the same `onoremap` is returning 0 everywhere (without changing anything else). Probably something is cached here...

Comment: After some further debugging it seems that when calling it from the `onoremap` all the cursor positions are the same for some reason. Not the case when calling it from command line.. No idea what is going on here.

Comment: OK just for info: I found what was wrong. It looks like expression-map blocks all "normal!" commands. Rewriting the function without them now. But not sure how to jump to a matching paren without %

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius, I have edited my post with 2 possible implementations that'll certainly need some tuning.

Comment: Thank you. I see a lot of useful things in there. Accepted.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius, Actually, this is still far from perfection. It'd be best to change scope detection to the non-trivial code I'm been using in [s:CurrentScope()](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/autoload/lh/cpp/AnalysisLib_Class.vim#L149) to detect C++ scopes (namespaces + classes) (This function will eventually move to another library plugin)